# jQuery Fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

**Здрасьте!**

Вот есть фейловый код для реализации динамического взаимодействия клиента с сервером( Ajax в jQuery ):

```
states = "1";

    bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "../ask.php",
      global: false,
      type: "GET",
      data: "GetStatuses",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(msg){
        states = msg; // "states" заводится локально внутри этой функции...
      }
   }
);

    alert(states);  // Вывод "1"
```

Почему переменная "перезаводится", как локальная внутри данной функции успеха Ajax-запроса? Как это можно исправить? **Большое спасибо!**

Comment: главное про `var` незабывайте

Answer (score 4):

Потому-что обработчик success выполняется не сразу (т.е. асинхронный).

Перепиши так и все будет работать:

```
states = "1";

    bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "../ask.php",
      global: false,
      type: "GET",
      data: "GetStatuses",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(msg){
        states = msg;
        alert(states); 
      }
   }
);
```

И фейл тут не jquery, а автора вопроса :)

Comment: Так, к сожалению, не катит. Но, спасибо, вы напомнили мне о том, что параметр асинхронности async по умолчанию стоит в true. Я поменял на:

     async: false,

Естественно, все заработало. Спасибо, что напомнили мне об этом. Плюсую)

Comment: Еще есть параметр async, если false будет выполнен синхронный запрос (кроме ``dataType: "jsonp"`` и кроссдоменных запросов). Deprecated. Асинхронность рулит.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - асинхронность действительно рулит :)

Comment: @Asen, а зачем вы меняете комментарии местами? Время не обманешь...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, что?